# Terraform not adding lambda integration_type to API Gateway despite having route and integration done properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, endpoint

A manually created API Gateway and lambda endpoint has this "/results" in lambda console:

[image: lj]

However when I try to create similar combination of API Gateway + lambda in another region using TF code, it has no "/result" at the end.

"API endpoint: [https://91oojllzci.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/"](https://91oojllzci.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/%22)

TF code:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api" "main_apigateway" {
  name          = "apigateway-vote"
  protocol_type = "HTTP"
  
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "default" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id

  name        = "$default"
  auto_deploy = true
}


# ###########################################
# # RESULT lambda backend integration
# ###########################################

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_integration" "result_integration" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id


  # I think this below should add lambda function to API endpoint - but it does not work.

  # integration_uri  = aws_lambda_function.result_lambda_backend.invoke_arn
  integration_uri = "${aws_lambda_function.result_lambda_backend.arn}"
  integration_type = "AWS_PROXY"
  payload_format_version = "2.0"
}

resource "aws_apigatewayv2_route" "result_route" {
  api_id    = aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.id
  route_key = "GET /results"
  target    = "integrations/${aws_apigatewayv2_integration.result_integration.id}"
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "result_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.result_lambda_backend.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.execution_arn}/*/*"
}
```

When looking into apigateway routes and integration it does have corresponding connected lambda "result" backend function. The "/result" lambda backend function is also created via TF code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "result_lambda_iam_role" {
  name               = "result_iam_role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Principal": {
       "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
     },
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Sid": ""
   }
 ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "result_log_policy" {

  name   = "result_log_policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": [
       "logs:CreateLogGroup",
       "logs:CreateLogStream",
       "logs:PutLogEvents"
     ],
     "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
     "Effect": "Allow"
   }
 ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_result_log_policy_to_iam_role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.result_lambda_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.result_log_policy.arn
}


resource "aws_iam_policy" "result_dynamodb_get_item_policy" {

  name   = "result_dynamodb_get_item_policy"
  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetShardIterator",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:GetRecords"
            ],
            "Resource": "${aws_dynamodb_table.dynamodb_table_votes.arn}/Votes"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}



resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach_result_dynamodb_get_item_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.result_lambda_iam_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.result_dynamodb_get_item_policy.arn
}



data "archive_file" "result_zip_code" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_file = "${path.module}/result.py"
  output_path = "${path.module}/result.zip"
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "result_lambda_backend" {
  filename      = "${path.module}/result.zip"
  function_name = "results"
  role          = aws_iam_role.result_lambda_iam_role.arn
  handler       = "result.lambda_handler"
  runtime       = "python3.9"

}
```

Why does it not add "/results" to API endpoint in lambda AWS console, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
name        = "$default"
```

change it to `result` and you will get `/result` at the end of the url

```
name        = "result"
```

Comment: i changed to "result" and it does produce the correct endpoint, but another manually created apigateway still has stage=default and has "results" attached. there should be one stage (like in the old manually created apigateway - $default). this is kinda not exactly what i wanted.

Comment: yes, actually this change is wrong, since for another lambda function it also adds "results" to the endpoint, while it should have its own "/voting". i checked my 2nd function "voting" and it has wrong api endpoint pointing to "/results"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the thing responsible is "resource_path" arg. It's not available in Terraform. So the way to do this is to add function name at the end of API endpoint manually (last line):

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "vote_permission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.vote_lambda_backend.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "${aws_apigatewayv2_api.main_apigateway.execution_arn}/*/*/results"
}
```